# How do you open a window and push it to the right from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, autohotkey

I'm using autohotkey on Windows 7, and I bound Ctrl+Alt+T to the command `run powershell.exe -noexit -WindowStyle Maximized`, which works, but I am partial to using powershell when it is pushed to the right half of my screen.  So whenever I do Ctrl+Alt+T, I then have to also do Super+Right Arrow to get it where I want.  I was wondering if it is possible to automatically run whatever command is run when you do Super+Right Arrow.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an API for the aero snap feature, but you can just automate the keypress with somethin like this:

```
^!t::
  psPid := 0
  Run, powershell.exe -noexit,,, psPid
  WinWait, ahk_pid %psPid%
  WinActivate
  Send, #{Right}
return
```